# Font awesome not found?

Tags: pdftex, texlive, moderncv, fontawesome

I have just installed LaTeX again on my system, and I was trying to compile my CV, which is a `moderncv` template, however I am getting that error that seems like FontAwesome package cannot be found.

When locating `FontAwesome--fontawesometwo` on the system with `locate -i FontAwesome--fontawesometwo` I get the current tfm path
`/home/user/texmf/tex/latex/fontawesome/tfm/FontAwesome--fontawesometwo.tfm` 
meaning it exist.

I know there are similar questions but no one does the trick for me yet.

The code minimalized is as follows:

```
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{green}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry} 
\firstname{myName} 
\familyname{familyName} 

\address{myAdress}{}
\mobile{myMobile}
\email{myEmail}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title


\section{Academic Info}
\cvitem{2013-2016}{some academic info}
\cventry{2011--2013}other academic info}{}{}{}{}


\section{working experience}
\cvitem{2016}{some working experience}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `locate` is not the correct way to search for it: what's the output from `kpsewhich FontAwesome--fontawesometwo.tfm`?

Comment: the oputput of `kpsewhich` is nothing..

Comment: What's your TeX distribution?

Comment: was TexLive 2015

Comment: What is your TeX distribution now, when you say, it "was" TeXLive 2015.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem by installing the TexLive 2016 version following the instructions for Linux in http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html